# How can I connect two angular apps with socket io?

Tags: angular, server, socket.io, port

I am trying to make a chat support system. I have two angular apps running on two different ports. App1(Customer) sends a message to App2(agent). I have trouble connecting the two apps via socket io. I just started learning socket io. So my knowledge is minimal. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: You would probably do this with a server in the middle and communication is facilitated by the server.

Comment: So, I shouldn't have two servers?

Comment: 2 clients (customer and agent - each using angular) and 1 server (running something built on nodejs or c#  or java or whatever).